# Trying to get Amazon reviews to go left and right of a picture

Tags: javascript, css

everyone. First time poster and I'm gonna go ahead and consider myself a novice when it comes to coding.

So I have a few Amazon reviews that I am wanting to go left and right of a picture that's in the middle of the page. That way I don't have a senseless empty/white space on the page. I am using external CSS and JS with my HTML.

```js
let data = [
    {
        review: 'I finished this book in three days because I COULD NOT PUT IT DOWN! I read page one, and I was a goner! If you enjoy romance, but also appreciate unpredictability, plot twists, with a side steam, look no further. Very much looking forward to the next book!'
    },
    {
        review: 'A great romance! The plot is very interesting and keeps you turning the pages. More and more romance today is all about lust and spice, but grateful for authors who still believe plot is important. This is a quick read. Very refreshing and clean (it does have 2 spicey scenes). Can\'t wait for the next book!'
    },
    {
        review: 'Finished the book in under 24 hours. It\'s absolutely riveting. Apparently it\'s the author\'s first book - and honestly I see a lot of talent in this young writer. There\'s lots of twists and turns that leaves me in suspense. I can also appreciate the military references so that it also has an appeal to the male audience. My wife absolutely loves this book and is fully immersed into the storyline - she describes it as a masterpiece and the fact that she got a sneak peek of the next book at the very end leaves her in high suspense and anxious for the next one to get published.'
    },
    {
        review: 'Good quick read with twists and a good ending!'
    },
    {
        review: 'A great romance! The plot is very interesting and keeps you turning the pages. More and more romance today is all about lust and spice, but grateful for authors who still believe plot is important. This is a quick read. Very refreshing and clean (it does have 2 spicey scenes). Can\'t wait for the next book!'
    }
];

const info = document.querySelector('#info')

let details = data.map(function(item) {
    return ('<div>' + item.review + '</div>')
})

info.innerHTML = details.join('\n')
```

```css
body {
    /* display: flex; */
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100hv;
}

#topBanner {
    background-color: #424347;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 25px 0 25px;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: auto;
    margin: auto;
}

.title {
    font-family: X Typewriter;
    font-size: x-large;
    letter-spacing: 2em;
    text-indent: 2em;
}

.subTitle {
    font-family: X Typewriter;
}

img {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    /* width: 50%; */
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#info {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;

}

#info div {
    padding: 3rem;
    background: lightgrey;
    margin: 0.5rem;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Uncovered: A Novel</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <section id="topBanner">
            <div>
                <h1 class="title">Uncovered</h1>
                <h2 class="subTitle">A Novel</h2>
            </div>
        </section><br><br><br><br>
        <img src="images/bookCoverMedium.jpg" alt="">
        <div id="info"></div>
        <script src="uncovered.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```